# Can't loop the distance between two locations. TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, geopy

I have a csv file with locations:
[image]

I have written a program that measures the distance between two locations. As I have many locations, I created a loop to iterate over the locations above.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

Data = pd.read_csv('/home/aziz/Desktop/langlat.csv')
data = pd.DataFrame(Data)
lat1 = data['Lattude'][2:]
lat = pd.DataFrame(np.array(lat1))
lang1 = data['Langitude'][2:]
lang = pd.DataFrame(np.array(lang1))

import geopy.distance


for i in range(len(lat)):
    for j in range(len(lat)):
        coords_1 = (all(lat[0][i]), all(lang[0][i]))
        coords_2 = (all(lat[0][j]), all(lang[0][j]))
        print(geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).km)
```

Yet, the output is:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

if I use this code, it will return the distance as desired.

```
coords_1 = (lat[0][3], lang[0][3])
coords_2 = (lat[0][5], lang[0][5])
print(geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).km)
```

Output

```
84.44162834864254
```

From a little research, I knew that my data is 1-D. But, I could not figure out a way to solve the problem. So, how can I make the program iterate over new locations?

part of the data:

```
Lattude,Langitude
,
26.332805,44.80257
24.849348,46.823551
,
24.848709,46.814429
24.585251,46.807482
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full traceback shows us exactly what is causing that error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rob/test/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    coords_1 = (all(lat[0][i]), all(lang[0][i]))
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Lose those `all`s and it works:

```
for i in range(len(lat)):
    for j in range(len(lat)):
        coords_1 = (lat[0][i], lang[0][i])
        coords_2 = (lat[0][j], lang[0][j])
        print(geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).km)
```

`lat[0][i]` for example is a single floating point number, and `all` expects an iterable type. I don't understand what you were trying to do with [`all`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/all).

Comment: I encountered `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. at the first time. So, I had to use `all()`. Anyway,  after I followed your instruction, I received this error `ValueError: Point coordinates must be finite. (nan, nan, 0.0) has been passed as coordinates.`

Comment: @AbdulazizAlJumaia I suspect your file contains blank lines. Try removing those lines. Or paste the csv file you are using into the question, I had to construct a fake one for testing, but I am happy to test with real data.

Comment: I have more than 11000 instances. But, I put 20 instances above. I did check out the data, they are fine. Only the second row is blank which is removed in the slices I put in the code. Could this be a problem from measuring the distance of the same location? @Rob Bricheno

Comment: @AbdulazizAlJumaia Please post the sample exactly as it appears in the CSV file, including commas, quotes, etc. I'm trying to reproduce your problem, which I can't do with data I have made up, so I need a real example of data that causes this issue. If I edit your data like this for example there is no issue https://pastebin.com/N7GpmeS8

Comment: Here is the sample https://pastebin.com/KKqz2rSH or you can go back to the question. I have edited it. I just noticed that there are blanks in the data. @Rob Bricheno

Comment: @AbdulazizAlJumaia Thanks! It is definitely those blanks that are causing the problem. You can either edit them out, or hide the problem by wrapping the `print` line inside a `try: ... except ValueError: ...` block.